How do I make forceatlas2 plugin on CDN based HTML?
I cannot seem to get forceAtlas2 to work with SigmaJS:
Uncaught TypeError: sigmaInstance.startForceAtlas2 is not a function

Everything I see for CDN libraries and force atlas layout is for Sigma v1 and they don't work. What do I need to include to make this work properly via CDN?
All of the storybook/examples I see are for importing the library, which I can't do.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Quick Sigma.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/2.4.0/sigma.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphology/0.25.4/graphology.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="flows.js"></script>
    <script src="zones.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: lightgrey">
<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; background: white"></div>
<script>
    const graph = new graphology.Graph({multi: true});
    // flows.forEach(function (flow) {
    //     console.log(flow);
    // });
    // Lay zones out on page...
    zones.forEach(function (c, counter) {
        graph.addNode(c.sys_id, {
            label: `${c.zone_name}`,
            color: c.zone_name.toLowerCase(),
            x: Math.random(),
            y: Math.random(),
            size: 20
        })
    });
    flows.forEach(function (flow) {
        // console.log(`${flow.source_zone} ->  ${flow.destination_zone}`);
        graph.addEdge(flow.source_zone, flow.destination_zone, {size: 2, label: flow.application_name})
    });
    const sigmaInstance = new Sigma(graph, document.getElementById("container"),
        {renderEdgeLabels: true}
    );
    sigmaInstance.startForceAtlas2()
    setTimeout(function(){sigmaInstance.stopForceAtlas2()}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>

